# Validating Phing's build.xml using Netbeans

Tags: php, xml, validation, netbeans, phing

I have the following `build.xml` file in my project's root directory (the file is taken from [Phing's manual](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<?xml-model href="/usr/local/php/lib/php/data/phing/etc/phing-grammar.rng" 
            type="application/xml" 
            schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0" ?>

<project name="FooBar" default="hi">
    <target name="hi">
        <echo msg="Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii" />
    </target>
</project>
```

I changed

```
<?xml-model href="/usr/share/php5/PEAR/data/phing/etc/phing-grammar.rng" 
                    type="application/xml" 
                    schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0" ?>
```

to refer to the correct path on my filesystem and confirmed that the file actually exists.

The `build.xml` is working correctly from the terminal and the it prints `hiiiiiiiiiiiii`.

My problem is 2 things:

1. When press `validate file` Netbeans gives the following error:

   XML validation started.
   Checking file:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/testComposer/build.xml...
   cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'project'. [6]
   XML validation finished.
2. I can't get Netbeans to auto complete the predefined tasks in Phing.

It seems Netbeans can't read the `phing-grammar.rng` file although it exists and has read permissions.

Is this a limitation of Netbeans or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is **xlink:** href. See example:

```
<?xml-model xlink:href="/your/path/to/phing-grammar.rng" type="application/xml" 
                    schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0" ?>
```